# Unable to send a body in a GET request in ReadyAPI/SOAPUI Pro

Tags: java, rest, groovy, soapui, ready-api

I am trying to send a Body(JSON) via **Get** Request using Ready API/SOAPUI Pro and unable to see an option to add a body in it whereas I can add a body in POSTMAN lastest version for GET request!

Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: why there are `groovy` and `java` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ready API.VmOptions file set config to True